# htaccess forward conflict with wordpress

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking to forward all but a few directory's of an old site to a new domain, so that the client still has access to the old sites data (i.e. the backend area of the wordpress site) as well as maintaining access to a specific directory due to the content it houses.

The rule I've set up definitely works on its own, but seems to have an issue when combined with wordpress's rules - I'm not great with htaccess stuff so I'm hoping it's something obvious and silly.

This is the htaccess in full (slightly redacted):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule !^(wp-admin(/.*)?|wp-login(/.*)?|shop2(/.*)?)$ http://newdomain.tld [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The /shop2/ directory works exactly as expected, i.e. all traffic to /shop2/ stays on the this domain and doesn't get forwarded.

However I get some odd behaviour with both wp-admin and wp-login. wp-admin forwards users to the new domain, ignoring the new rule, however it does include the 'redirect_to' URL parameter like it would on the actual wp-admin page. wp-login doesn't forward, but it loads an unstyled 404 page.

I'm assuming there's a conflict in the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule !^((wp-admin|shop2)(/.*)?|wp-login\.php)$ http://newdomain.tld/ [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

In general keep redirect rules before internal WP rules.

Comment: That is logical - I'll give it a try!

Comment: Doesn't seem to have made a difference from what I can tell. I've ensured to clear all site data (as I know htaccess changes can be tricky to test due to caching etc.)

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser when it didn't redirect to `http://newdomain.tld/`? And does `/wp-admin/` also have a .htaccess?

Comment: `wp-admin` doesn't have its own .htaccess. http://newdomain.tld/shop2/ works as intended, i.e. doesn't forward the traffic. http://newdomain.tld/wp-admin/ seems to still forward the traffic. Could it be due to a lack of access to `index.php`? Does there need to be a clause for that? i.e. it looks like `wp-admin` may try to access `index.php`, which would of course result in a forward.

Comment: Looking at the Network report in the dev tools `/wp-admin/` is `302`ing to /wp-login and then getting `301`'d to the new domain.

Comment: Hang-on I've been stupid. 'wp-login' isn't a directory, it's a file, so there actually needs to be a clause for `wp-login.php`. How would I squeeze that into your better formed rule?